# How to redirect to current page if process has an internal error laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to ask.

I have registration page using laravel. There is no issue in my register controller for create user/insert data in database.. I also include  send email in register controller. The issue start when my server have error email connection. When this happen, laravel will redirect registration page to server error page. How can I make even the email connection is lost, it will redirect to registration page with error message?

Register Controller:

```
protected function create(Request $data)
    {
        $newUser = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $name = array('name'=> $data['name']);

        $data->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        Mail::send('mails.success_register', $name, function($message) use($data){
            $message->to($data->email);
            $message->subject('Successful Registration Confirmation');
        });

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Congrats! You account has been succesfully created.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use try-catch:

```
try {
    Mail::send('mails.success_register', $name, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->to($data->email);
        $message->subject('Successful Registration Confirmation');
    });
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect('everywhere-you-want')->with('error', 'something went wrong');
}
```

you can also put all of your code inside try-catch